# json NSNumber unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c, json

I am trying to get a Number from a json response but I keep getting error :

```
objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa00000065646f434
```

Here is my code:

```
   NSNumber *FaultCode;
         NSArray *detailsFault = json[@"GetResponse"][@"GetResult"][@"Faults"][@"FaultException"];

        for (NSDictionary *fault in detailsFault){
            NSLog(@"%@", fault[@"Code"]);
            FaultCode = fault[@"Code"];
        }
```

It works fine for Strings but for the other data but it fails when trying to use on this which is just a number.

Here is the json:

```
{ "GetResponse":{ "GetResult":{ "Faults":{ "FaultException":{ "Code":1234, "Message":"It has failed" } }, "Response":null } } }
```

Comment: I don't see any arrays in that JSON.  Also the error message you post is incomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution

```
NSString *str = @"{ \"GetResponse\":{ \"GetResult\":{ \"Faults\":{ \"FaultException\":{ \"Code\":1234, \"Message\":\"It has failed\" } }, \"Response\":null } } }";


    NSData *data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];


    NSNumber *FaultCode;
    NSDictionary *detailsFault = json[@"GetResponse"][@"GetResult"][@"Faults"][@"FaultException"];

    NSLog(@"%@", detailsFault[@"Code"]);
    FaultCode = detailsFault[@"Code"];
```

Don't need the loop you already have diction when you get "FaultException"

Comment: Excellent, thank you, I have removed the loop from all other parts too. I was missing to use NSDictionary at that point. Thanks for your help

Comment: BTW: It is easier to use KVC on key path than keyed subscripting: `[json valueForKeyPath:@"GetResponse.GetResult.Faults.FaultException"]`.